# function/procedure to calculate total based on total for each month in plqsl

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I need advice on how to write a stored procedure or function to calculate total based on total of each month. Lets say:

- target income for Jan = 20K, then for a month: 20K * 31 (total days of January)
- target income for Feb = 19K, then for a month 19K * 28 (total days of February)

I need to get total up to the given date. For instance:

date_param = 25 February 2018. Then grand total = (20K * 31) + (19K * 25)

How to write this in pl/sql?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the target income for the other months?

Comment: Presumably these months and their targets are stored in a table?

Comment: @APC, targets yes, but not months. Targets are stored as daily. For instance, Target for January is 25$. Thus, for January months its 25$ * 31 (total days of Jan).

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, it does not matter what is the target income for the other months. Can be assumed any number.

Comment: What is rhe structure of the table which holds the target values?

Answer (score 0):

Your question remains rather light on specifics, so here are my  assumptions.

1. The daily targets are stored in a table with a structure of
   `(month_no number, daily_tgt number)`.
2. The targets are the same for each year.
3. The calculation starts from the first month of the current year.
4. There is no need to handle leap years.
5. The presented question rules out the need to handle non-working days.

This solution is a function to return the calculated total.

```
create or replace function get_target_sum 
     (p_cutoff in date)
     return number
as
    rv number;
begin
    select sum(daily_tgt * no_of_days) 
    into rv
    from (
    select daily_tgt
           , case when month_no < to_number(to_char(p_cutoff, 'MM'))
               then to_number(to_char(last_day(to_date(month_no,'MM')), 'DD'))
               else to_number(to_char(p_cutoff, 'DD')) 
             end  as no_of_days
        from targets
        where month_no <= to_number(to_char(p_cutoff, 'MM'))
      );
    return rv;
end;
/
```

**Notes**

- Storing the daily targets by numeric month make it easier to filter the months before the cut-off date in the WHERE clause.
- Casting the month number to a date allows us to derive the last day of the month from which we get the number of days to multiply for whole months.
- For the final month we just need the day from the cut-off date.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear as in stating how to get the Monthly rates. I assumed few things and providing my solution as below:

1) Created a table `mnthly_tgt` which would store monthly rates.

2) The function will take an input date and then return the sum from past months of the year.

Table Definition:

```
Create table mnthly_tgt(mnth number, tgt_amt number);

insert into mnthly_tgt values(1 , 15);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(2, 20);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(3 , 12);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(4 , 10);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(5 , 11);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(6, 15);
insert into mnthly_tgt values(7, 20);
```

Function:

```
Create or replace function Ret_Tot(ipt_dt date)
return number 
is

v_curr_mnth  number;
v_curr_days  number;
v_tot_amt    number;
v_sql varchar2(400);
v_date   date;
v_num_of_days  number;
cntr number:=0;

begin

 -- Calculating total for current month.

   Select  to_char(ipt_dt,'MM')  col1      -- Current Month   
          ,to_char(ipt_dt,'dd')   col3      -- Days in Current Month  
    INTO 
       v_curr_mnth ,
       v_curr_days             
   from DUAL;

   -- Current Month Total
   v_tot_amt: = v_curr_days *  (Select tgt_amt from mnthly_tgt where mnth = v_curr_mnth);


  --Calculation for previous months

   For i in (Select  to_char(ipt_dt,'MM') - LEVEL  col1  
             from Dual
             CONNECT BY LEVEL < to_char(col,'MM')   
   Loop

     cntr := cntr + 1;

     v_sql:='Select ipt_dt - INTERVAL '|| cntr ||' MONTH from DUAL'  ;   

     Execute Immediate v_sql INTO V_DATE;

     --calculating no. of days of previous months  
     v_sql:='SELECT EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY('|| V_DATE ||'))  FROM dual';

     Execute Immediate v_sql INTO  v_num_of_days ;

     --Summing up total      
     v_tot_amt: = v_tot_amt + ( v_num_of_days * (Select tgt_amt from mnthly_tgt where mnth = i.col1));

   END LOOP; 

 return v_tot_amt;

end;
```

PS: Nt tested.